# removing a dynamicaly created button while in run time vb2008

Tags: vb.net

My program currently creates buttons and assigns them values during run-time, and this works.

My issue is now I'm trying to remove them.

I've researched the problem, but I'm still having issues.

Here is the code that runs when the Menu item is clicked:

```
Private Sub RemoveDriverToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RemoveDriverToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim removedriver As Integer

    Dim newbtn1 As Integer 

    removedriver = InputBox("Driver to remove ", " Driver number to remove")

    If removedriver = newbtn1 Then

        FLP.Controls.Remove(newbtn1)

        newbtn1.dispose()

    End If

End Sub
```

Note: the buttons value is in the .Text value

I want to be able to input a number in the message box to instruct the program to delete that corresponding button.

Comment: Why the vb6 tag?  This is clearly .net code.

Comment: Hi there. To ask a good question on StackOverflow, it's important that you provide the details of the issues you are facing. It isn't sufficient to just say "still having issues". You should ideally tell us what the issues are, e.g. the program runs without error but doesn't do what you want (in which case you need to say what it currently does and what it should do), or if you get an error, tell us what line of code causes the error, what inputs you used, and what the exception details are. Otherwise, your question might be closed as off-topic.

Comment: ok thank you for the info ill rember that for the next time

Answer (score 0):

Hei,
as I can see you are on the right way, but **newbtn1** is an integer.
newbtn1 should be a button control ( should be THE button conrol to remove ).

Also try Me instead of FLP

```
Dim searchList as New List(of Control)
Set   searchList = Me.Controls
For each c as Control in searchList 
  if c.text = "THE BUTTON YOU WANT TO DELETE" Then
    Set newbtn1 = c
    exit for
  end if
Next
Me.Controls.Remove(newbtn1)
```

Comment: i see  that also, i  had to create the newbtn as button and newbtn1 as the control im going to try and figure that out but if i fail ill try your option  Thanks

Comment: '' Your search criteria here ( maybe the text / caption of the button ? ) 
this means use if c.caption = "The Button Caption of the button you want" then 
newbtn1= c 
exit for 
end if